# Get Control/Window info when listening to user events on non-Windows systems

Tags: node.js, linux, macos, electron, ui-automation

we are building electron app that should work cross-platform and listen to user events and get some basic info about them.

On Windows we use separate .NET process build using UIA to get some basic info, not just about application that is being interacted with, but also about the actual control in the application. We can get `AutomationElement` from clicked point or on focus change and get from there `Name`, `WindowName`, `ControlType` etc.

Is there something similar for Mac, Linux or any OS for devices that you know of? And can it be accessed from Node.js or it has to be build with as separate app for that OS (with Objective C or Swift)?

I was reading about Cocoa and Cocoa Touch, and they have `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask` and `addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`, but it seems it doesn't go deep as to actual control within the app.

So, what could be used on Mac or Linux like UIA is on Windows?